# Настройка nginx для websocket соединения

Tags: nginx

Пытаюсь настроить nginx для websocket соединений, но nginx отказывается принимать соединения и сразу отклоняет его с кодом ошибки 400. Соединение не доходит до backend сервера. (nginx и backend общаются через сокет, указанный в upstream). Без nginx всё работает отлично, и http соединения с nginx тоже работают отлично. Конфиг для nginx взял из официальной документации: https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/websocket.html.

Итак, мой конфиг:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
  listen 5000 ssl http2;
  client_max_body_size 5M;

  ssl_certificate /home/server/deployment/my_site.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/server/deployment/ssl/my_site.key;

  server_name my_site.ru;

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://uvicorn;
  }
}

upstream uvicorn {
  server unix:/home/server/chat/uvicorn.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема была в протоколе. Я пытался использовать протокол `ws`, но видимо из-за того, что в конфиге указан `ssl`, nginx хочет, чтобы для сокета был протокол `wss`. После смены `ws` на `wss` всё заработало